# A model window using function setTimerOut and with jquery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Do anyone know how to combine these 2 javascript together ? which is setTimeout function for modal window and cookie function for modal window . I'm new in javascript don't know how to write these 2 function together , wish someone to help out .I had set "TimerOut" function for modal window after page loaded and display .On the other side , I set cookie for it too ,I just need modal window display in once .Now the TimerOut function was overlapping the cookie function . Thanks in advance ! 
here my code .

Modal window settimerout function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var show = function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
};

$(window).load(function(){
    var timer = window.setTimeout(show,3000);
});
</script>
```

Modal window with cookie function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bs-docs-sidebar').affix({
        offset: {
          top: 10
        }
    })
    if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $.cookie('pop', '7');
            }
});

$(function($) {
$('#deleteCookie').click(function() {
        $.cookie('pop', null);
        window.location.reload();
      });
 });
```

Comment: Together means ? did you want these in a same file ? or in a same function ? what did you mean ?

Comment: Hi Arunprasanth , thanks for replied my question , I need to use these 2 function together for a modal window ... but how can I do that ? Its need to write in 1 statement right ?

Comment: You can use these two codes where ever you want, that is not a matter , its only depends on where did you call these, include these two codes in a single .js file and include it in your client side and you can use it where ever you want

Comment: can't ..it's seem like two function crashed together .. I set "TimerOut" function for modal window after page loaded and display .On the other side , I set cookie for it too ,I just need modal window display in once .Now the TimerOut function was overlapping the cookie function . http://cloudsblack.com/modalwindow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overlapping occur because $(window).load() function execute after your cookie function. If you not require $(window).load() then use $(document).ready().

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = window.setTimeout(function(){$('#myModal').modal('show');},3000);
    $('.bs-docs-sidebar').affix({
        offset: {
          top: 10
        }
    })
    if($.cookie('pop') == null) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $.cookie('pop', '7');
    }
    $('#deleteCookie').click(function() {
        $.cookie('pop', null);
        window.location.reload();
    });
});

</script>
```

Here i am not use load function if you need then you can use it.

Comment: Hi Sunny , Thanks for answering my question ,still is not working ,the cookies function did't work .

Comment: Make you sure that include cookie jquery file. for example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: yes , I already put jquery.cookie.js but the cookie function still not working ? http://www.cloudsblack.com/modalwindow.html . thanks

Comment: I show that you make cookie null. instead of null can you set 0 and check cookie with 0. I think this is a problem.

Comment: I removed null and set to 0 .if($.cookie('pop') == 0) {  $.cookie('pop', 0);  but not working too